# Is there a way to pass arguments using the dot operator in python?

Tags: python, class, overloading, argument-passing

I'd like to the make a clean, "smart" method that performs specific operations  without passing in arguments. I have some code that works in principle as follows:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, spam='spam', ham='ham'):
        self.spam = spam
        self.ham = ham

    def bar(self, arg):
        # spam operation
        if arg == self.spam:
            return self.spam*2
        # ham operation
        elif arg == self.ham:
            return self.ham*3
```

Notice the `bar` method is written to perform different operations on `spam` and `ham`.  Implementing this code would return:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.bar(foo.spam)                      # returns 'spamspam'
foo.bar(foo.ham)                       # returns 'hamhamham'
```

Unfortunately, I'm having to use `foo` twice to access a specific operation in `bar`, which is awkward and tedious.  Is there a cleaner, Pythonic way to get the same results without passing in arguments?  For example, is it possible to overload the dot (.) operator to the get the same results with:

```
# Ideal 1
foo = Foo()
foo.bar.spam                          # bar knows to use spam operation
foo.bar.ham                           # bar knows to use ham operation
```

or even better

```
# Ideal 2
foo = Foo()
foo.spam.bar                          # bar knows to use spam operation
foo.ham.bar                           # bar knows to use ham operation
```

Comment: You could make `bar` a class instead of a def, and then overload the `__getattribute__` on bar

Comment: Here's a question - why do you want to call `bar` for both of these? Why not just create a `foo.barspam()` and a `foo.barham()`? Each of these could internally call a `bar` method with the proper arguments that the end caller doesn't need to care about. If these are actually fixed internal variables that you're referencing, it seems silly to dispatch this dynamically.

Comment: thank you @wim.  Your suggestion is appropriate prior to my edit (Ideal 1).  I will try this out.  Not sure how/if it works for Ideal 2.

Comment: @Amber This is a good point for the Ideal1 case as written, so I made an edit to add Ideal 2 (what I'm really after). I'd like the user to have the flexibility to access attributes with `foo.spam` or return an operation quickly with `foo.spam.bar`.  thanks.

Comment: I think `__getattr__` can meet your need.

Comment: I have to agree with @Amber. Also, you may consider the legibility and semantics of your code. For sure, in Python almost everything is possible, but how clearer your code can be doing what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Updated to parametize the options.

Here is something using object composition:

```
class Pork(object):
    def __init__(self, name, mult):
        self.name = name
        self.mult = mult

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self.name * self.mult

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, spam='spam', ham='ham'):
        self.spam = Pork(spam, 2)
        self.ham = Pork(ham, 3)
```

Results:

```
In [638]: foo = Foo()

In [639]: foo.spam.bar
Out[639]: 'spamspam'
In [641]: foo.ham.bar
Out[641]: 'hamhamham'
```

Comment: Great answer!  This pretty much solves my problem.  For completeness, I recommend adding the appropriate conditional statements to return the correct values of `foo.ham.bar`.  @salparadise I'll wait for you to edit then accept the answer, or I can edit it for you.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @pylang lots of ways to skin the cat, but I think parametirizing the amount of times you want to print is one good way. Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Thanks @salparadise you answered my question elegantly.  FYI to readers - this method works really well when using passing strings.  `__repr__` appears to return a str and change the obj representation to a string.   Passing in other types however does not work as well i.e. numbers with (replacing `__repr__` with `__int__` or  `__float__`) and not for lists.   Thanks again.